# Select Multiple rows then join for each row

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores each `location` a `user` is watching. the table is called `usercity` and is pictured below an example row.

[image]

I need to `SELECT` all rows WHERE `user_id='1'`, and then retrieve each `location_id`'s record from the `location` table, which is pictured below:

[image]

I am not really sure where to start here, but here's my lame attempt:

```
   SELECT b.* FROM usercity a JOIN location b ON a.location_id=b.id WHERE user_id='1'
```

**Edit My query Works with one record. not sure if it will work with multiple rows.**

Answer (score 1):

try below-

```
select a.*, b.* 
from usercity a JOIN location b ON a.location_id=b.id
WHERE user_id=:uid
```

Answer (score 1):

If its one-to-one relation then you can use `inner join`

```
select
uc.*,
l.* from usercity uc
join location l on l.location_id = uc.location_id
where l.user_id=:uid
```

Comment: i don't know what that means. my knowledge of SQL is very basic to below average

Comment: What I meant for each entry in `usercity` there is one entry in `location` connected by `location_id` thats called `one-to-one`, if you have multiple records for the same `location_id` in `location` then its `one-to-many`, so in the 2nd case when you do join it will return multiple rows matching the 2 tables, and in case of one-to-one you just get one row.

Comment: Then just simple join is good, if you remove the where condition then you will get all the matching records from both tables, right now it will return only for supplied `user_id`

Comment: i understand basic SQL, just not JOINS and stuff. they confuse me

Comment: Here is a nice tutorials on JOIN have a look http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0):

well, i kept playing with it and got what i want:

`SELECT b.* FROM usercity a JOIN location b ON a.location_id=b.id WHERE user_id='1'`

I guess SQL is one of those things you learn through practice.